# How can I add some text line in my window?

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I am able to create a window with a Tile. How can I add now new text line inside the Window ?

All what I succeed to did was only to change the title of the window which is not what I want . I want to add some text line in the window box.

SendMessage function was not working for me.

Please if somebody has some tip for this to tell me !

```
#include <windows.h>

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";
//The Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    // Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }


    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "Title of window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        1390, 540, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);



    // The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext

Answer (score 1):

To draw text in the client area, your `wndProc` would normally use something like `DrawText` or `TextOut`. You typically do that in response to `WM_PAINT`.

To be able to respond to an external message, you'd typically send a message containing the text. The window would receive that, store (a copy of) the text it received, and (usually) invalidate the window's rectangle. Since the window is now invalidated, the next chance it gets, Windows will send your window a `WM_PAINT` message (and then you'll draw out the text).

Answer (score 0):

Handling the `WM_PAINT` message and drawing the text directly on the window's `HDC` is one option.

Another option is to create a child [STATIC control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/static-controls) in your window, and then you can assign the desired text to that child using [`SetWindowText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtextw) or the [`WM_SETTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-settext) message.  No manual drawing needed.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figure out how to finish this:

[win32 app picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v04uO.jpg)

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
using namespace std;

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int X_Coordinate = 215;
int Y_Coordinate = 415;
int Width = 700;
int Height = 500;

char Text[] = {"abc123"};

char Window_Title[] = "My title";
char Window_Image[] = "D:\\bitmap1.bmp";


const char* csWindow_Title = Window_Title;
const char* csWindow_Image = Window_Image;


HBITMAP bitmap; // Creates bitmap object based on a handle to a Windows Windows Graphics Device Interface (GDI) bitmap and a handle to a GDI palette.


// Utilities
bool ConvertConstChartoLPWSTR (const char* as , wchar_t* wString  )
{
    memset(wString,0,sizeof(wString));
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, as, -1, wString, 4096);
    return wString;

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{


    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    //Registering the Window Class
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255)); // set window background color ( RGB ) - white

    RegisterClass(&wc);  // register the window class with the operating system

    wchar_t* wWindow_Title=new wchar_t[4096];
    memset(wWindow_Title,0,sizeof(wWindow_Title)); // init variable
    ConvertConstChartoLPWSTR(csWindow_Title,wWindow_Title); // convert


    // Create the window.
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        wWindow_Title,                  // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,           // Window style


        // Size and position
        X_Coordinate, Y_Coordinate, Width, Height,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
        );


    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}


//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

// ----------------------------- START -> SWITCH case -----------------------------------------------------

    switch (uMsg)
    {

// ----------------------------- START -> case WM_DESTROY -------------------------------------------------
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
// ----------------------------- END -> case WM_DESTROY ---------------------------------------------------


// ----------------------------- START -> case WM_PAINT ---------------------------------------------------
    case WM_PAINT:
        {

            wchar_t* wWindow_Image=new wchar_t[4096];
            memset(wWindow_Image,0,sizeof(wWindow_Image));
            ConvertConstChartoLPWSTR(csWindow_Image,wWindow_Image); // convert

            bitmap=(HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,          // A handle to the module that contains the image to be loaded. To load a stand-alone resource (icon, cursor, or bitmap file)—for example, c:\myimage.bmp — set this parameter to NULL
                                      wWindow_Image, // The image to be loaded.
                                      IMAGE_BITMAP,  // The type of image to be loaded.
                                      690, // The width, in pixels, of the icon or cursor.
                                      540, // he height, in pixels, of the icon or cursor.
                                      LR_LOADFROMFILE); //Loads the stand-alone image from the file specified by lpszName (icon, cursor, or bitmap file).

            PAINTSTRUCT ps; // declare structure with information for an application
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);  // prepare the specified window for painting


            int index = sizeof(Text);


            HDC hMemDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); // create a compatible DC ( hMemDC ) o be the same like another one ( hdc )
            ::SelectObject(hMemDC,bitmap); // Selects an object into the specified device context (DC). The new object replaces the previous object of the same type.

            long retval=SetTextAlign(hdc,TA_TOP); // alignment of written area


            const char* theval;
            int u = 5;

            for(int b = 0; b < sizeof(Text); b++)
             {
                string sym(1, Text[b]);   // convert char to const char*

                theval = sym.c_str();

                cout<<b<<theval;    

                wchar_t wtext[sizeof(Text)];
                memset(wtext,0,sizeof(wtext));
                ConvertConstChartoLPWSTR(theval,wtext); // convert


                // Here application is laid out.
                TextOut (hdc, 5, u, wtext, sizeof(Text)); 
                u = u + 15;
             }

                index = index + u; // claculate the size of written area

                BitBlt(  hdc,       // handler
                         0,         // The x-coordinate, in logical units, of the upper-left corner of the destination rectangle.
                         index,     // The y-coordinate, in logical units, of the upper-left corner of the destination rectangle.
                         700,       // The width, in logical units, of the source and destination rectangles.
                         980,       // The height, in logical units, of the source and the destination rectangles.
                         hMemDC,    // handler for source ( image ).
                         0,         // The x-coordinate, in logical units, of the upper-left corner of the source rectangle.
                         0,         // The y-coordinate, in logical units, of the upper-left corner of the source rectangle.
                         SRCCOPY ); // A raster-operation code. These codes define how the color data for the source rectangle is to be combined with the color data for the destination rectangle to achieve the final color.
                                    // SRCCOPY - Copies the source rectangle directly to the destination rectangle.


               EndPaint(hwnd, &ps); // function marks the end of painting in the specified window
        }
        return 0;

// ----------------------------- END -> case WM_PAINT ---------------------------------------------------


    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
// ----------------------------- END -> SWITCH case -----------------------------------------------------

} // END -> LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc
```